# Difference between "rank" and "score"

Tags: differences

I am computing a scoring system for employee performance.  I will have elements that need to be ranked a value 0-5 depending on employee's depth on that element.  The elements will be weighted and a final score computed.  For example, Communication is ranked 4, weighted 80%, and score is 3.2 (4*80%).

**Is "rank" and "score" used correctly here?  How are these items best expressed for what I am doing with them?**

Comment: Yes. Sounds alright. I think though that I might use the term *overall score* just to make it clear. Because others are not bound to follow your terminology and may start talking about *their score for communication* etc.

Comment: I planned to label this scoring system "Performance Weighted Ranking" (PoWeR) and refer to the summed scores (i.e., all overall score as WS2 stated) as the "PoWeR Score".  Does that sound redundant since Ranking (R in PoWeR) and Score appear together?

Comment: The terms have only vague definitions.  You need to define them.  Absent definitions, many would take ranking to be something done after scoring is complete, or before the scoring process is even started.

Comment: Why use Rank 0-5 ? Does it mean you compared the employees and then ranked them ? Best Employee = Rank1, Worst Employee = Rank5 ? If that value is not a comparison, then use Points. Then calculate overall Score. ((Now highest Score is automatically Rank 1 & lowest Score is Rank N, where N is the number of employees)) Now, can you assign POWER as POints WEighted Rank ?

Comment: I agree with Lawrence's answer: "rank" is the wrong term.  What you have is elements that will be given a **raw score** of 0-5; a **weight** will be assigned, and then a **weighted score** will be calculated.  The employee's final score will presumably be the sum of the weighted scores of the elements.

Comment: The way I'm using rank is to assign a value against the standard. If we have tasks A and B, an employee slightly proficient in A may be ranked a 2; another person who's an expert in A may receive a 5. For B, same prices, but since it's less important overall for the employee, I weighed B some percent less than 100% while A might be weighed 100%. This gives me the weighted score for each item and a summed score for the employee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rank refers to a relative ordering (first, second, third, etc), while score refers to an accumulation of points.

From dictionary.com:

> Rank
> 5. relative position or standing
>
> Score
> 2.
> the total points or strokes made by one side, individual, play, game, etc.

In your example, you assign an employee's Communication a value of 4. The context suggests that this is not necessarily because the person came fourth in the group, so that value is a *score*, not a *rank*.

You can call the "3.2" figure a *final score* or *weighted sum*.

Comment: +1, Rank is always a whole number, while Score can be fractional.

Comment: @Prem - Rank can be A, B C, or gold, silver, bronze, or any other ordering of categories.  And let's not forget that D- you got in math.

Comment: @HotLicks , Ah, yes !! But that is still equivalent to whole number !! ((In my school D=Distinguished , A=Average, E=Exemplary, F=Fail)

Comment: @Prem "D minus" isn't "distinguished" in the US.

Comment: (And I've never seen a fractional score in a baseball game.)

Comment: @HotLicks , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_the_United_States : *ABCD ~ grades* ; In general , rank is a positional whole number ; I have never seen students who were ranked 5.17 , while students can have that number as grades or scores.

Comment: Page Rank'(algorithm) is described in fractional number and is about relative position.

Comment: @Bigair I'd treat that name (with upper case letters and an oddly placed apostrophe) as a proper noun. It's not using the term "rank" in the way the word is commonly understood if that measure admits fractions.